# Suppose $(A, \le)$ is a partially ordered set. Define a relation $\preceq$ on $A\times A$ by $(a,b)\preceq (c,d)$ if

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

if and only if

1) $a\le c$ and $a \ne c$

2) $a = c$ and  $b\le d$

Prove that $(A\times A,\preceq)$ is also a partially ordered set.

So to prove this I would start with trying to find 1) Reflexivity, 2) anti-symmetricy and 3) Transitivity right?

How would I do that, does the $A\times A$ mean anything special in this case?

For Reflexivity would i say 1) since $\le$ is reflexive then that means $A\le A$ ... I just dont know how to begin this?

Comment: I presume $A * A$ means $A\times A$, the *Cartesian product* of set $A$ with itself:  $A \times A = \{(a, b)\mid a \in A, b \in A\}$

Comment: I took the liberty of replacing the somewhat awkward notations $<<$ and $<<<$ by $\le$ and $\preceq$, respectively, and I corrected $A*$ to $A\times A$, the Cartesian product.

Comment: Question, why would they use <<, <<< in the first place? and just letting you know it cant be a <= c since a in not equal to c?

Comment: I expect that they used those symbols partly to emphasize that these orders are not necessarily any orders that you’ve seen before and partly because they’re easy to produce on a standard keyboard. And it **is** $a\le c$; clause (1) handles the case in which $a\ne c$, and clause (2) the case in which $a=c$, but both are allowed to occur. If you like, you can introduce $a<c$ as an abbreviation for ‘$a\le c$ and $a\ne c$’, and similarly for $\prec$, but the partial orders $\le$ and $\preceq$ are clearly intended to allow the possibility of equality.

Answer (score 1):

The order $\preceq$ on $A\times A$ is known as the [*lexicographic order*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) induced by $\le$. $A\times A$ is the Cartesian product of $A$ with itself: $A\times A=\{\langle a,b\rangle:a,b\in A\}$. To show that $\preceq$ is a partial order on $A\times A$, you do indeed have to show that it’s reflexive, transitive, and antisymmetric.

- **Reflexive:** You must show that for every $\langle a,b\rangle\in A\times A$, $\langle a,b\rangle\preceq\langle a,b\rangle$. This is completely straightforward: just check the definition of $\preceq$.
- **Transitive:** You must show that if $\langle a_0,b_0\rangle,\langle a_1,b_1\rangle,\langle a_2,b_2\rangle\in A\times A$, $\langle a_0,b_0\rangle\preceq\langle a_1,b_1\rangle$, and $\langle a_1,b_1\rangle\preceq\langle a_2,b_2\rangle$, then $\langle a_0,b_0\rangle\preceq\langle a_2,b_2\rangle$. Since the definition of $\preceq$ has two clauses, you’ll have to consider several cases. I’ll do one of them to get you started. Suppose that $\langle a_0,b_0\rangle\preceq\langle a_1,b_1\rangle$ because $a_0\le a_1$ and $a_0\ne a_1$. We know that $a_1\le a_2$ (why?), so $a_0\le a_2$ and $a_0\ne a_2$, and therefore $\langle a_0,b_0\rangle\preceq\langle a_2,b_2\rangle$, as desired.
- **Antisymmetry:** You must show that if $\langle a_0,b_0\rangle,\langle a_1,b_1\rangle\in A\times A$, $\langle a_0,b_0\rangle\preceq\langle a_1,b_1\rangle$, and $\langle a_1,b_1\rangle\preceq\langle a_0,b_0\rangle$, then $\langle a_0,b_0\rangle=\langle a_1,b_1\rangle$. Here again I’ll get you started. Suppose that $\langle a_0,b_0\rangle\preceq\langle a_1,b_1\rangle$ because $a_0\le a_1$ and $a_0\ne a_1$; then $a_1\not\le a_0$ (why?), and it is therefore impossible to have $\langle a_1,b_1\rangle\preceq\langle a_0,b_0\rangle$. Thus, we must have $a_0=a_1$ and $b_0\le b_1$. Now finish the argument by showing that $b_0=b_1$.

Comment: is the definition is either related or equal so since (a,b) = (a,b) it is reflexive since the condition is related or equal?

Comment: so a = a and b << b, so because << can be equal it would also hold that b<<b so therefor since a=a, b<<b we know that (a,b) <<< (a,b)

Comment: thats for reflexivity, is it correct?

Comment: to show that b0 = b1 do we try and make b<<b, so that then for that to be true it would have to be b = b, b<<b (reflexive)? @Brian M. Scott

Comment: We know that $a_1\le a_2$ (why?). Why do we know this, is it because we supposed it at the start, because the only way for it to be transitive is if it was related?

Comment: i have resigned myself to failure...

Comment: I am now sacrificing a goat in hopes my prayers will be answered...

Comment: is mathematics considered torture?

Comment: in desperation i believe i have figured it out, well lets just say i have written down something that i hope will prove to be extremely accurate

Comment: @Ghozt: It’s a little hard to tell, but I think that you got the reflexivity more or less right: $a=a$, and $b\le b$ (since $b=b$), so by clause (2) $\langle a,b\rangle\preceq\langle a,b\rangle$. I can’t make much sense out of your fourth comment. For the fifth, we didn’t actually assume that $a_1\le a_2$: we assumed that $\langle a_1,b_1\rangle\preceq\langle a_2,b_2\rangle$. However, whether this is true by clause (1) or by clause (2) of the definition of $\preceq$, it implies that $a_1\le a_2$. We assumed (for that case) that $a_0<a_1$, so $a_0<a_1\le a_2$, and therefore $a_0<a_2$.